# permission issues with `apt-get download` "couldn't drop privileges" and "permission denied for user '_apt'

Tags: apt, updates, permissions

```
:~$ sudo apt-get download snap
Get:1 http://ftp.energotel.sk/pub/linux/ubuntu/archive yakkety/universe amd64 snap amd64 2013-11-29-1ubuntu2 [375 kB]
Fetched 375 kB in 5s (67.6 kB/s)
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/home/abanoubg/snap_2013-11-29-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
```

Comment: This is just a **W**arning, so it is not necessarily a problem. Did everything else work fine?

Comment: i was trying to get unity8 on my ubuntu 16:10

Comment: The question needs more detail.

Comment: i want know why this shown and what is mean ?

Answer (score 1):

Just run the command without the `sudo` part:

```
apt-get download snap
```